# Trying to get property 'nom_matiere' of non-object laravel shows me this error

Tags: laravel

i want to display the name of matiere in this page but he shows me this error Trying to get property 'nom_matiere' of non-object

i make a selection in the note page to select the matiere then give a note to here it work but when i display the name of matiere in my table it give me error

model note

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
 {
 protected $fillable = ['note'];


 public function matieres() 
  {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Matiere::class);
    }
```

}

model matiere

```
   <?php

    namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Matiere extends Model
    {
    protected $fillable = ['nom_matiere','coef'];


     public function notes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Note::class);
   }


  }
```

my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Note;
use App\Matiere;


class NoteController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{

      $notes = Note::paginate(5);
      $matieres = Matiere::all();
    return view('admin.notes',compact('notes','matieres'));
}



public function store(Request $request)
{
    Note::create($request->all());




     session()->flash('success',' cette note  a été enregistré avec succés');


       return redirect()->back();
}



public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $note = Note::findOrFail($request->note_id);
     $note = Matiere::findOrFail($request->note_id);

    $note->update($request->all());
    session()->flash('success','cette note a été modifié avec succés');

   return redirect()->back();
}


public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    $note = Note::findOrFail($request->note_id);
    $note->delete();
    session()->flash('success','cette note a  été supprimé avec succés');
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

}

my view

```
          <section id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
              <thead class="cf">
                <tr>
                <th>id-note</th>
                  <th>La note</th>
                  <th>nom matiere</th>
                 <th>les actions</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($notes as $note)
                  <tr>

                  <td class="numeric"  data-title="id-note" >{{$note->id}}</td>
                  <td class="numeric"  data-title="Nom">{{$note->note}}</td>

                   <td class="numeric"  data-title="Nom">{{$note->matiere->nom_matiere}}</td>

                   <td>
                        <button href="#editEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-theme"  data-target="#editEmployeeModal "data-mynote="{{$note->note}}"   "data-mymatiere="{{$note->nom_matiere}}" data-catid={{$note->id}}  class="edit" data-toggle="modal"  ><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i> </button>
                        <button href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-theme" data-target="#deleteEmployeeModal" data-catid={{$note->id}} class="delete" data-toggle="modal" > <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i> </button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
              </tbody>
              @endforeach

            </table>
            <div class="text-center">
              {{ $notes->links() }}
        </div>
            <div class="clearfix">

            <div class="hint-text">Affichage de  <b>5</b> sur <b>25</b> entrées</div>

           <div id="addEmployeeModal"  href="create" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form   action="{{route('notes.store')}}" method="post">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="modal-header">            
        <h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter note</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">          
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>La note</label>
          <input type="text"  id="note" name="note" class="form-control" required>
        </div>



    </div>
    <div class="form-group select">
    <select name="matiere_id">
      <option value="">--selectionner la mtiére svp --</option>

    @foreach($matieres as $matiere)
        <option value="{{ $matiere->id }}">{{ $matiere->nom_matiere }}</option>
    @endforeach  
  </select> 
  </select>
</div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Annuler">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Ajouter">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your database table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `$note->matiere` in your view but the relationship is called `matieres`, which would be a collection.

Instead of:

```
<td class="numeric" data-title="Nom">{{ $note->matiere->nom_matiere }}</td>
```

You'd need:

```
<td class="numeric" data-title="Nom">
    @foreach ($note->matieres as $matiere)
        {{ $matiere->nom_matiere }}
    @endforeach
</td>
```

I do however suspect that you have set your relationship up wrong. You've got the Note -> Matiere relationship set to `belongsToMany`, which means that you need a pivot table to contain the FK relationships. This would only be used if your `Note` is the child of many `Matiere`.

It does sound like you have your relationships set up wrong, but without really understanding what you're trying to do it's hard to tell you what exactly needs to be done.

Separate issue, but in your class `update()` method you've also got:

```php
$note = Note::findOrFail($request->note_id);
$note = Matiere::findOrFail($request->note_id);

$note->update($request->all());
```

This means that you actually update the `Matiere` model no the `Note` model.

Comment: i have a relationship many to many between note and matiere and i create a table note_matiere what is wrong in my relationship !??